# Distinct not working in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 and trying to select distinct records from items table but not working this my query:

```
$items = DB::table('items')
        ->join('stock_item','stock_item.stm_id','=','items.item_id')
        ->select('stock_item.stm_id','stock_item.item_name','items.id','items.status','items.quantity')
        ->distinct('items.item_id')
        ->where('items.quantity','>', 0)->where('status','0')->get();
```

any help.

dd($items)'s result .The result snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Why is not working? What are expected and real results?

Comment: Which row do you want to keep in the result set

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking the following solution

```
$items = DB::table('items')
        ->join('stock_item','stock_item.stm_id','=','items.item_id')
        ->select('stock_item.stm_id','stock_item.item_name','items.id','items.status','items.quantity')
        ->where('items.quantity','>', 0)->where('status','0')
        ->groupBy('items.item_id')->get();
```

You don't need **distinct** to get the result which is attached in the questions.

Comment: Here 10K Breast Chicken is repeated which is not what I want.

Comment: Instead of groupBy('items.item_id') try this groupBy('stock_item.stm_id'). If possible then share the items and stock_item tables.